# What's a good term to denote a fixed cost?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for the X in the following sentence:

> Cost: $5 per item plus $20 X

The X is a fixed cost paid once, no matter how many items are bought. This line is for a formal business documentation.

Comment: What is it paying for?

Comment: Would not _fee_ be a word you could use?

Comment: @Matt: I'm selling files containing aggregated data. The overhead is there just to encourage the client to buy more than a single file and has absolutely no relation to shipping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would **overhead** work for your purposes?

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overhead?show=2&t=1302641540):

> **over·head**
>
> 1. **business expenses (as rent, insurance, or heating) not chargeable to a particular part of the work or product**
> 2. ceiling; especially : the ceiling of a ship's compartment
> 3. a stroke in a racket game made above head height : smash

Answer (score 3):

You could flip it, and say it's $25, plus $5 for each additional item.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the nature of it. For a flat fee, I'd say reorder:

> Cost: $20 plus $5 per item

For a startup cost, use something like *initial* or *base* fee:

> Cost: $5 per item plus $20 base

For a minimum item cost:

> Cost: $5 per item plus $20 minimum

Answer (score 1):

Can't think of a specific contract term - it's normally put under "handling" or "shipping and handling"

Answer (score 1):

For the example you provide, *surcharge* would be an excellent option:

> Cost: $5 per item plus $20 surcharge

*Flat rate* is also a standard term for what you describe:

> Cost: $5 per item plus $20 flat rate

Definitions (NOAD):

> **[surcharge](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1295988#m_en_us1295988)**
>   an additional charge or payment
>
> **[flat rate](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1247615#m_en_us1247615)**
>   a charge that is the same in all cases , not varying in proportion with something: